# Use Gmail with different account than in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

Up until now I was able to use in Gmail different Google Account than in Chrome. Today I have reinstalled Chrome from scratch and I can clearly see that:

- whenever I login to Chrome with account A, I am also logged in with this account in Gmail,
- whenever I logout in Gmail (to login with account B), I am also logged out from Chrome and my synchronisation stops.

Things that I have checked or considered so far:

1. I know that I can [add another account (i.e. account B) to Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), different than used in Chrome, but the problem is that whenever I restart Chrome and open Gmail, I am again signed in to Gmail with account A and I must switch manually to account B.
2. I know that I can [mark one of my accounts as default](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-do-i-change-my-default-account-with-google-multiple-sign-in), but this isn't a solution for me, because it marks my account as default everywhere, not just on this particular PC / browser.
3. I am aware of [a solution for a well known bug in Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/NXCd-27yRek), but this solution doesn't work for me.

How can I fix this? How can I have Google Chrome always signed to account A and Google Gmail always signed to account B?

Answer (score 1):

This [a well know bug](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/NXCd-27yRek) however workaround ("best answer" [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/NXCd-27yRek)) given for it didn't work for me and I had to [modify it a little bit](http://onezeronull.com/2018/10/23/use-gmail-with-different-account-than-in-chrome/):

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags` in the URL bar.
2. Search for `consistency` to find *Identity consistency between browser and cookie jar* option.
3. Change its value to `Enabled Dice (fix auth errors)`.
4. Relaunch, as advised.

This will restart Google Chrome showing you that there was an error in Chrome sync functionality.

[image]

Then (there will be a lot of relaunches, as in good-old Windows times):

1. Login to **account A** in *Google Chrome* / synchronisation settings.
2. Once correctly signed-in, restart Chrome.
3. Navigate in any tab to any Google app (i.e. Gmail). Verify that you're logged in to **account A**.
4. Log-off and in "Login again" screen *remove all remembered accounts*.
5. Make sure that you're still logged in to **account A** in *Google Chrome*.
6. Restart Chrome again.
7. Log in to **account B** in *Gmail* or any other *Google app*.
8. Verify that you're logged in to different account in that *Google app* than in *Google Chrome*, that *this app* is working (try to refresh page few times) and that the synchronisation process in *Google Chrome* is also working.
9. Restart Chrome for the last time to verify that situation is correctly replicated after relaunch.

Optionally, you may want to restart entire PC to confirm that even after full system relaunch you're still logged in to **account B** in *Gmail* and to **account A** in *Google Chrome*.

One more thing to underline. Switching between accounts in *Google Chrome* (i.e. logging to a different accounts there) causes it to create new icons on taskbar. Ignore all of them and always use (pin to taskbar) a shortcut created on your desktop when initially installing Google Chrome!

(you may safely remove shortcut from your desktop, once it is pinned to taskbar)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to log into a different gmail account, regardless of what's logged into the main windows, you could use a *new incognito window*.

Or use another browser profile, perhaps with this command line option (excerpt from chromium's linux man page):

> `--user-data-dir=DIR`
>
> Specifies the directory that user data (your "profile") is kept in.   Defaults  to
>   `$HOME/.config/chromium`  .   Separate  instances of chromium must use separate user
>                 data directories; repeated invocations of chromium will reuse an existing  process
>                 for a given user data directory.

Comment: That's sounds like a good idea for one-time shot, not for an everyday usage (i.e. when you want different Gmail's and Chrome's accounts to be used on day-to-day basis).

Comment: If you're always using two gmail accounts it might be acceptable, or using another profile logged in & synced to the other account works too